# Perform a search for a user input date that falls between two dates

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have been trying to create a search that pulls up all of the records with a user specified date that falls between the start and end dates of that record. I also want to user to be able to pull it up by "Property" unless they leave it blank.

I am very new to VBA as in started yesterday and this is the latest version that I could come up with:

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()
    Dim strFilter As String

    strFilter = [Start_Date] <= Format(Me.RateDate, "Short Date") _
    And [End_Date] >= Format(Me.RateDate, "Short Date")

    If Not IsNull(Me.Property) Then
        strFilter = strFilter & " AND [Num_Code] = '" & Me.Property & "'"
    End If
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_RatesAll", acViewPreview, , strFilter
End Sub
```

The most recent error message returns: Run-time error '2465': Microsoft Access can't find '|1' referred to in your expression.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: See if [this](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=184554) thread helps you. Hint: You have `strFilter` as a `String` but aren't formatting your input as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strFilter = "[Start_Date] <= #" Me.RateDate & "# And [End_Date] >= #" & Me.RateDate & "#"
```

Should do it.
What you had is being taken as a literal string and not using the values you desired.

Comment: I put your line in and it gave me the error "Compile Error: Expected: Expression" and highlighted the first #.

Comment: It was missing an & before the first Me.RateDate but it worked then. Thanks!